# How do I reduce the screen and file size of a recorded video, plus convert to FLV?

Tags: mp4, recordmydesktop, video-conversion, ogg-vorbis, flv

I have used gtk-recordMyDesktop to make a video as an OGV file using the default settings. I need to do 3 things:

1. How can I reduce the screen resolution (height and width) so that it can fit into a smaller video size on my website?
2. How can I pull out like every third frame so that the file size is not so large, yet not mess up the sound?
3. Not all Windows IE users can view OGV files. How can I convert to FLV (or, as a fallback, MP4) so that I can share on my blog?

Comment: @Samik, please make that an answer, it's a great comment!

Comment: @Samik, of course! I recommend adding a comment re the 2nd q that for modern codecs such as OGV/FLV/MP4, adjusting the bitrate is a better way to control the final file size rather than decimation (reducing frame rate by dropping frames)

Comment: I'm having a problem choosing which is the best answer the one from Samik or Mitch. They both sound so good. Right now I'm running ffmpeg to see the outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can resize and convert with `ffmpeg` using `ffmpeg -i input.ogv -s widthxheight -sameq output.flv`. 
You can also change the video bit rate with `-b:v bitarate` and control the frame rate with `-r framerate` to reduce the size of outcome. As [izx](https://askubuntu.com/users/58612/izx) has mentioned the bit rate option is recommended over changing frame rate or dropping frames.

Comment: Where can I find documentation on the bitrate in human-readable terms? I'm not certain what value to put there.

Comment: @Volomike You can use human-readable format like for 64Kb/s you should use `-b:v 64k`. You can consult to [`ffmpeg` documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Description) and also the man page (`man ffmpeg`)

Comment: I get "unrecognized option '-b:v'", unfortunately.

Comment: @Volomike Sorry for that inconvenience, did you get over it? It can happen if `ffmpeg` version is very old. You can use `-b` instead. Newer versions allows you to separately change video and audio bit rate with `-b` set default to audio.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Avidemux

[image]

> Avidemux is a free video editor used mainly for simple cutting,
>   filtering and encoding tasks. It is often dubbed as the VirtualDub for
>   Linux as it can do many things that VirtualDub can do. It supports
>   many files types, including avi, DVD compatible mpeg files, mp4, asf
>   and even the not-so-common ogm and matroska format.
>
> Some of the useful features of Avidemux include a simple WYSIWYG
>   interface, easy conversion from one format to another, plenty of
>   filtering effects and a built-in subtitles processing capabilities.

Source: USC

You can also use Pitivi Video Editor

[image]

Adding a Screencast / Video Clip into Pitivi

> In order to add video clips into your Pitivi project, simply click on
>   IMPORT CLIPS and select the appropriate video file. Note: video file
>   clips can also relate to screen-casts created with
>   gtk-recordmydesktop. The Pitivi video editor accepts many different
>   video clip file formats.
>
> Examples of Accepted File Formats:
>
> - MPEG
> - AVI
> - MP4
> - OGV (Ogg Theora Vorbis)

<sup>Source: http://zenit.senecac.on.ca/wiki/index.php/Using_Pitivi_Non-Linear_Video_Editor</sup>

To add the video clip into the project area, simply click and drag the object into the area below the Timeline Ruler. Quoted from [this site](http://zenit.senecac.on.ca/wiki/index.php/Using_Pitivi_Non-Linear_Video_Editor)

After you import the file, add it to the timeline, and do your editing, click on the render button, and it will allow you to save the file as .flv. [image]

Comment: This didn't work too well. It wouldn't let me open an OGV file.

Comment: Pitivi has no export option that I could see.

Comment: You have to import the file to edit it

Comment: I did import it into Pitivi, but unfortunately there was no option to export in a different format. Note I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS still.